# LCD 16x2 not taking commands from MSP430FR2355

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, msp430, assembly

I have been facing this issue for about a week, and after hours of trying to debug it, I was hoping I could find some help here. I have been trying to use an LCD 16x2 screen (unaware of the exact model but have been using this [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/ADM1602K-NSW-FBS-3.3v.pdf)) and display some simple text on it with my MSP430FR2355 using MSP430 Assembly. Most of my code has come from me attempting to translate C libraries for displaying text into assembly. The LCD powers on and the Vss, Vdd, and Vo pins are all working fine. When it powers on it just displays the top line as a row of rectangle characters. My pin map is as follows:

```
RS - P2.0

RW - P2.1

E  - P2.2

D0 - P3.0

D1 - P3.1

D2 - P3.2

D3 - P1.3 (P3.3 is broken)

D4 - P3.4

D5 - P3.5

D6 - P3.6

D7 - P3.7
```

The wirings have been checked many times and I have used a logic analyzer on every single pin RS-D7. All of these tests have shown that the pins are going high and low correctly and the way they should. The full assembly file can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/T1bH9MAX) (do ignore my silly code comments). The result of the code is that none of the commands do anything, after all the commands the screen just stays as a single row of rectangles. Thank you for taking the time to help me and if this is the wrong forum for this please direct me to the right one! :D

I also did my best to make a schematic of my current setup but I'm very new to this so it might not be great.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5hiaC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also here are photos of my LCD screen https://imgur.com/a/SXDUFv0

**Update**

I have ordered a new LCD because I'm pretty sure the problems are caused by the fact my current one has an I2C backpack soldered on it and that I'm not using it. I will update this post again when I receive the new LCD.

**Update 2**

I have received my new LCD screen without the I2C backpack but I am still experiencing issues. Running my program does nothing **but** sometimes randomly the first initializing command will work and will change the screen from 1 line to 2 lines. This is the only command I can get to work and even then it takes a few tries. I'm basically completely lost on where to go from here. I have updated the schematics to my current setup and my updated code is [here](https://pastebin.com/0E73v6pE). Any and all help is appreciated.

Photo of the screen on power up: https://imgur.com/a/LIbCDqi

Photo of the screen after the one command goes through: https://imgur.com/a/GjRXWIG

**Update 3**

It turns out that I had the ground wiring wrong and now the code is working great with the new LCD! Thank you @Justme, @6v6gt, and @Jens for their combined help!

Comment: The top row of rectangle characters may mean the Vo is not working fine. How have you determined that it works fine? Can you show the logic analyzer captures to verify the sequences are fine or not?

Comment: @Justme I have Vo hooked up to a potentiometer and turning the potentiometer changes the contrast. I assumed that the row of rectangle characters was an intended output for when the LCD was first given power, is that not the case? I did not use the logic analyzer on Vss, Vdd, and Vo but I can test them if you want the results. If so what should I be testing, just the change of voltage when turning the potentiometer? Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: No, the dark boxes of rectangle characters is not supposed to happen. The display should be clear when powered up and it means the contrast voltage is way off the limits of having a proper output from the display. Also do not use a logic analyzer on Vss, Vdd and Vo, why even mention it? Show the logic capture of the data and control bus.

Comment: @Justme I can turn the contrast down to where the boxes don’t show up but they show up when I turn it up. I can provide screenshots of the logic capture results in a little bit.

Comment: I am not familiar with MSP430 assembly but do you ever set RS bit high to send data instead of commands? You also seem to specifically turn the display off and never turn it on. I bet the C code did work and you are not doing the exact same things in assembly.

Comment: @Justme yes I do set the RS bit to high on line 86 when I try and send data. The reason I am specifically turning the display off is to test to see if the commands are actually being received. After running that command the screen doesn't turn off, signifying that the command wasn't received.

Comment: The display is off after a powerup. You can't see anything if you don't turn the display on. Except for the black boxes when the contrast is beyond sensible limits.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the simple things. Boot it up in auto-run and feed it data. It took me 3,000 lines of MPLAB assembler to drive a 40 character x 4 line LCD for test equipment. Have patience and think it through

Comment: You use an OR operation in line 136. You should clear the bit on entry of set_payload to be sure it is off because OR cannot clear it.

Comment: You need an endless loop (jmp $) at line 188 or the CPU will continue with executing instructions and do random things.

Comment: @Jens I just implemented your two suggestions but the commands still seem to not be received. My current code is here: https://pastebin.com/3Vk2bHiz

Comment: It is possible, that your display needs 5 V signal amplitude at the inputs because the supply is 5 V, but the MCU only provides 3 V signals. The 7805 needs a capacitor of some uF at the output for proper regulation. If you provide pictures of both sides of the display, someone may recognize the model and you can find the correct datasheet.

Comment: @Jens I have uploaded pictures of the display

Comment: Well, there is an I2C to parallel converter (PCF8574) mounted on the rear side of the display! This module occupies all the display inputs, you cannot connect your MCU port as intended and your software has no chance here. The whole discussion is more or less useless.

Comment: @Jens I didn’t think those pins were necessary. How do I use them?

Comment: Either you remove this module or you port e.g. the LiquidCrystal_I2C Arduino library to MSP430 assembler and use the I2C interface.

Comment: @Jens how do I remove the module? Would it just be easier to get a new LCD?

Comment: @Pixeled Why on earth you omitted the info about there being an I2C backpack? Of course that is the reason it does not work because you are supposed to drive it via the I2C.

Comment: @Justme I didn’t understand that that would be important and stop it from working. I’m still quite new to this all. I’m sorry for wasting so much of your time.

Comment: @Pixeled You have changed the display and code. This is not the same question it started with any more.  Your original question was answered. With new display and new code, it might have been better to start a new question.

Comment: @Justme Sorry I didn't consider that and I already made the bounty.

Comment: I have a very simple C++ (Arduino) program which sets up a 1602 screen (HD44780 controller) in 8 bit mode and sends a "HELLO" message to it without using a library: See https://forum.arduino.cc/t/lcd-1602-and-similar-databus-sniffer/675769/41 attachment LCD1602_write_V0_05.ino . The code for test_group 2 sends that message. Note that it expects the R/W pin to be grounded. The timings appear uncritical for this test. The display should be power cycled before the test. It may help you to get something displayed.

Comment: @Pixeled You are sending a clear command. Why? It takes ~50x times more time to execute than the other commands, you are not checking the busy flag, and I can't see how long the delays are anyway.

Comment: @Pixeled Is this "V" for victory: `mov.b #01010110b, payload` ?  What is `delay_4000` in microseconds on your target board ? This datasheet may be better for programming your HD44780 (clone) controller based display https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf

Comment: @6v6gt I’m mainly just trying to get any character to appear so yeah I just chose V. delay_4000 is just a shortcut to my delay subroutine. The clock is a 1Mhz 12 bit clock. So 4000 cycles would be 4 milliseconds.

Comment: @Justme do you think I should try and read the busy flag and see if that's the problem?

Comment: @Pixeled On page 40 of the data sheet at https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf there is a very similar example of the sequence necessary to force a message on the display as you are attempting. The difference is that the example uses a 1 line display. However, your code already sends the correct "Function Set" sequence (0x38) for your 2 line display. Note there is no "Clear Screen" in that sequence.  That example assumes the display is power cycled before each test. If you wait > 1.52 ms between sending each instruction you do not need to use the busy flag.

Comment: @6v6gt so should I remove the clear screen command and try copying the page 40 example?

Comment: @Pixeled Yes. Try removing clear screen. Apart from that and the function set your code doesn't appear to differ significantly from the example. If you are still having problems then suspect the power supply. The data sheet specifies power up should be complete within 10ms. You appear to be missing capacitors around the voltage regulator. Does your logic analyser have a decoder for the HD44780 protocol as used by that display controller?  Saleae for example has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

There is an I2C backpack on the display that was never mentioned. There cannot be both the backpack and the MCU driving the LCD parallel bus at the same time.

The intention of the backpack is to allow connecting the LCD to host with 4 wires only, and the I2C IO expander is driving the LCD parallel bus. And it is driving it in 4-bit mode.

So either remove the backpack, or use another display that has the parallel interface not taken by a I2C backpack.

---

You never turn the display on in code, so it can't show any data you write to it.

And if you get black boxes on top row, it means that there is too much contrast (drive voltage) so even unlit segments turn on. It also means the display is not initialized to operate in 2-row mode.

And the last problem is, there is no ground wire between MCU and LCD. They cannot communicate at all so now the behaviour makes sense and the display really did not take any commands or data.

After connecting a ground wire, you should see that the display initializes to 2-line mode, even if you don't fix the code otherwise, and turning the contrast up way too high will darken two lines with black squares instead of just one line.

Comment: Here is a photo of the screen when just the Vss, Vdd, and Vo pins are plugged in:
https://imgur.com/3zel1yN
I don't know if I'm just mistaken but it looks like it is on to me.

also here is the logic analyzer for the data pins: https://imgur.com/8QN0KI2
and here is the logic analyzer for the control pins (RS at the top, RW in the middle, and E at the bottom): https://imgur.com/bjtx0BX

Comment: @Pixeled That is how the display looks when it is "off", which simply means no segment is turned on, and you have too much contrast, and the second line not enabled. You can of course measure voltage on Vo pin and we can see if that is valid or not.

Comment: so then that is what it looks like when off? I tried switching the command to instead turn the screen on. When I ran that nothing changed, so I'm pretty sure the command is not being received.

Comment: So is the display being off and it not having power supposed to look different? Also then what does it look like when the display is on?

Comment: @Pixeled Based on logic analyzer captures the commands should be sent OK. Maybe the wiring is not OK, have you checked it? Also are you using 3.3V or 5V supply for the display? Please note that you may have a wildly different display, even if the commands are identical.

Comment: The MSP430 is powered by my laptop and I use a 6V power supply for the screen. I run the 6V through a voltage regulator to turn it into 5V and then use that to power the screen. I also take the original 6V power and hook it up to a B10k Potentiometer which then controls the contrast.

Comment: @Pixeled The display should look almost identical when LCD has no power and when all segments are off, because you can't turn on segments without power. But with too much contrast, segments turn on even if set to off, so you can't see a difference between a properly turned on segment and a segment that is kept off but turned on by excess contrast.

Comment: When I unplug the contrast the screen stays powered on though

Comment: @Pixeled Too many details missing. Like MSP supply, and if the MCU does not run on 5V but display does, how are you level shifting between a 3.3 MCU and 5V display, and I still cannot be sure how exactly the contrast pin connects to supplies, ground or potentiometer.

Comment: @Pixeled What do you mean by "stays powered" Are you looking at the separately powered backlight, which will stay on as long as you power the backlight? But I don't even know if your device has a backlight, but surely unplugging the contrast would leave backlight on and turn off all segments.

Comment: the display and MSP power are seperate. I have the MSP430 hooked up to my laptop while the screen is hooked up to a power supply powered through AA batteries. By stays powered I mean the screen is still lit blue and the backlight remains on. The backlight is powered through the screen power supply and I do not use the A and K pins.

Comment: @Pixeled Now the supplies are separate? Are the supplies really separate or have you connected the MSP430 ground pin to LCD ground pin? This is why drawing schematics is important. How is the display really connected from each pin to somewhere, how is potentiometer connected, how are power supplies connected, etc?

Comment: https://imgur.com/x37yvVM The batteries are hooked up to the breadboard. the ground and power are then sent to the voltage regulator and the output and ground is sent to the other side of the breadboard. then they are linked up the Vss and Vdd. The original 6V power is also hooked up the potentiometer whose output is set to the Vo pin. The MSP430 is powered via USB-C from my laptop. I have also tried 3V power and then removing the voltage regulator, which did not make a difference.

Comment: @Pixeled Yes but if you only have 8 data wires and 3 control wires from MCU to display, it can't possibly ever work. For same reason you can't light up a LED with only one wire to battery.

Comment: I’m confused, why would it never work? 8 data wires and 3 control wires is all there is

Comment: @Pixeled The MCU and LCD need a common reference potential between them. The LCD is powered by a battery that has an unrelated and floating potential compared to the MCU potential. If you set an IO pin to 0V or 3.3V, in reference to MCU 0V ground potential, the LCD doesn't know anything about the voltage in relation to it's own 0V supply. Drawing the schematic how things are connected and two devices not having a ground connection would have been easy to spot instead of describing things in text, as obviously the correct assumption is that the devices have grounds properly connected.

Comment: I had no clue that the devices had to share a ground connection. I'm still quite new to this all. How would I go about having them share the ground connection? Would just having their ground wires connected to the same breadboard do the trick? Sorry if that's a dumb question

Comment: @Pixeled Yes connect the two grounds together with a wire.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a bit confused on how I would set that up. Should I have a 6V power source for the display and a 3V for the MCU? Or should I just use a resistor to get the 6V down to around 3V for the MCU?

Comment: So I decided to go with having a separate 3V power supply for the MSU and just linking up the ground connections. My setup is this currently: https://imgur.com/eHzo09C . The ground from the voltage regulator, ground to LCD, ground from 3V, and ground to MCU. Although both devices are powered on, the screen still does not change when the code is run. Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: I'm just now seeing you edited your answer and said that once I connect the ground wires the LCD should initialize to 2 lines. This is not the case and it still just is one line and not receiving any commands. Did I hook up the ground wires wrong?

Comment: @Pixeled Please draw a schematic diagram how thigs are connected. It is difficult to decipher your wiring if the wires go out of the photo.

Comment: Sure thing, what software do you recommend?

Comment: @Pixeled Pen and paper will do. Or use the schematic diagram feature embedded on this website.

Comment: I just edited the post with my schematic, sorry if it's not perfect as I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing. Let me know if it makes sense or not

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be sending 0x38 (function set instruction) one time. The LCD datasheet you linked shows it uses a ST7066 controller (or equivalent). Looking at the [ST7066 datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/st7066.pdf) 8-bit interface (page 19) you need to send the function set instruction (0x38) three times not just once.

Comment: That usually is not necessary. The display starts up into 8-bit mode when powered up propely, so there should be no need to send 0x38 multiple times. It is just a good thing to do so, but only becomes necessary if the MCU would ever set the display to 4-bit mode - the init sequence has to be robust to handle all cases.

Comment: In an ideal case sure. But he said "When it powers on it just displays the top line as a row of rectangle characters.". This is an indication that the power up initialization is not working. I would just stick with the flow diagram in the controller datasheet until he finds out what the problem is. Then he can experiment to see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: No the problem was the same without even the MCU and LCD grounds being connected. And there was no rectangle characters because it is an artifact of too high contrast driving the LCD glass with too high voltage. The only thing working is the LCD power-up reset because the first line appears as it is driven off. Unless the 6V from batteries has fried it with overvoltage.